# combine two regex for angularjs form field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

How to combine this two regex for angularjs form field

```
\d{4}([- ]*)\d{6,7}
```

OR

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12}
```

I tried like this

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{4}([- ]*)\d{6,7} | [a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12}" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.username" required placeholder="username">
```

Comment: Sorry I tried but it not worked

Comment: Could you provide some sample strings to test against? How didn't your pattern work? What did it match/fail to match? Also, `pattern` is a HTML5 attribute, and you cannot have spaces around `|`. You can try with `ng-pattern="/^(\d{4}([- ]*)\d{6,7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12})$/"`

Comment: So, the problem was just a typo, those 2 spaces?

Comment: Why did you remove that other question? It may be useful for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the alternative of 2 regular expressions, you need to wrap them both in parentheses:

```
<input type="text" pattern="(\d{4}([- ]*)\d{6,7})|([a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12})" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.username" required placeholder="username">
```

Comment: It was my mistake, so that second regex is completely violating to the first one. so I made it like this :  `(\d{4}([- ]*)\d{6,7})|([a-zA-Z]{4,12})`

Comment: Thanks your help fixed my problem

Comment: One does not have to put the alternative branches into capturing groups each, the only problem were the 2 spaces around `|`. `pattern="\d{4}[- ]*\d{6,7}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,12}"` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that angular uses single pipe symbol for filters and you are not allowed to use it within the templates. Usual case would be a binary OR but your case may also have the problem...

So what you can do is creating a variable on a controller which holds your pattern and use the variable in the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="myctrl.pattern" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.username" required placeholder="username">
```